# Pass a javascript object through POST request

Tags: javascript, post, javascript-objects

I want to send and receive a javascript object through a POST request parameter. As a result, I need to find a solution to encode and decode it.

`JSON.stringify()` won't work because my JS object may contain functions.

I am also trying to avoid the option of sending it as a file, as it would introduce extra complexities, like introducing `module.exports` and `require` on sending and receiving sides respectively.

Any possible solution for my problem?

Comment: You can't send functions through the internet.

Comment: "my JS object may contain functions" — This is almost always a really bad idea. Design a data format to remove the need to do that if you can.